# Django: Filter a QuerySet and select results foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, I have two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    # lots of fields

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    member = models.BooleanField()
```

I need to construct a query that filters B and selects all A, something like this:

```
result = B.objects.filter(member=True).a
```

Above example code will of course return an error `QuerySet has no attribute 'a'`

Expected result:
a QuerySet containing only A objects

**Whats the best and fastest way to achieve the desired functionality?**

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting. `filter()` returns a queryset, not an instance, so it wouldn't have an `a` attribute; the elements in the queryset have that attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like

```
result = A.objects.filter(b__member=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Andrey Zarubin's answer would be to iterate over the queryset you had and create a list of a objects.

```
b_objects = B.objects.filter(member=True)
a_objects = [result.a for result in b_objects]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will not filter everything but it will filter all the values with respect to field, might be you are looking for same

B.objects.filter(member=True).filter(a__somefield='some value')